# AdaptiveCard - parse(json) == undefined

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

I am trying to parse a Adaptive card but the `parsedCard` variable is `undefined`.

```
let cardObject = $.parseJSON('{"$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json","type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"0.5","speak":"<s>TheforecastforSeattleJanuary20ismostlyclearwithaHighof51degreesandLowof40degrees</s>","body":[{"type":"Container","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Seattle,Washington-January20,7:30AM","isSubtle":true}]},{"type":"Container","items":[{"type":"ColumnSet","columns":[{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"Image","url":"http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/MostlyCloudy-Square.png","size":"small","horizontalAlignment":"center"}]},{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"ColumnSet","columns":[{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"42","size":"extraLarge"}]},{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"°F","weight":"bolder"}]}]},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"MostlyClear","isSubtle":true}]},{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Hi51"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Lo40"}]}]}]}]}');
let adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
let parsedCard = adaptiveCard.parse(cardObject);
let htmlElement = parsedCard.render();
```

Comment: Check that your cardObject is correct JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the `parse` method doesn't return anything. Try the following:

```
let cardObject = $.parseJSON('{"$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json","type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"0.5","speak":"<s>TheforecastforSeattleJanuary20ismostlyclearwithaHighof51degreesandLowof40degrees</s>","body":[{"type":"Container","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Seattle,Washington-January20,7:30AM","isSubtle":true}]},{"type":"Container","items":[{"type":"ColumnSet","columns":[{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"Image","url":"http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/MostlyCloudy-Square.png","size":"small","horizontalAlignment":"center"}]},{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"ColumnSet","columns":[{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"42","size":"extraLarge"}]},{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"°F","weight":"bolder"}]}]},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"MostlyClear","isSubtle":true}]},{"type":"Column","size":"auto","items":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Hi51"},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Lo40"}]}]}]}]}');
let adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
adaptiveCard.parse(cardObject);
let htmlElement = adaptiveCard.render();
```